# Convert a string into date from netcdf file

Tags: python

I have a string that looks like this: 2020102800
Where: Year = 2020, Month = 10, Date = 28, Hour = 00

How can I convert it into "10/28/2020 00Z"?

Comment: I tried this:
from datetime import datetime
date_time_str = '2020102800'
date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%y%m%d%H')
print("The type of the date is now",  type(date_time_obj))

But this gives me an error:
ValueError: unconverted data remains: 800

Comment: [Edit] instead of commenting to add details.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 str="2020102800"

    date= str[4:5]+'/'+str[6:7]+'/'+str[0:3]+' '+str[8:9]+'z'
    print date
```

str[4:5] means pick character from `str` at position 4 to 5.
str[0:3] means pick character from `str` at position 0 to 3.
Just pick the string you want and add them together.

Answer (score 0):

The comment on your post is nearly there, you just need to use the correct [format code](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) for strptime()

```py
from datetime import datetime

date_string = "2020102800"
print(datetime.strptime(date_string, "%Y%m%d%H"))
```

Output:

```
2020-10-28 00:00:00
```